# Physical switch to VM firewall/router for Router-on-a-stick?

Tags: networking, firewall, vmware-workstation, opnsense

I'm planning to purchase a TP-Link T2500G-10TS (TL-SG3210) switch for home lab. I already have a dell server with quad-port NIC which I will connect to the switch and I'll make VLANs.

The server connects to the switch, the switch connects to my laptop which will run OPNsense VM in VMware Workstation.

My question is can I use an OPNsense VM (running in VMware Workstation) to have a Router-on-a-stick configuration with a physical switch, or is this only possible with a physical firewall/router ?

I'm unwilling to purchase a physical firewall/router to save money if Router-on-a-stick is possible with a physical switch to firewall/router VM.

Comment: Router on a stick is possible and there are multiple guides on how to do so with OpenWrt and an IoT device like a Pi or Arduino. Software-based routers, which is what you're asking about, function the same as hardware appliances _(for example, I run Sophos UTM as a software appliance router within an ESXi VM)_, but you must have a minimum of two networking ports [ethernet, fiber, USB-to-ethernet, etc.] for it to work _(Inbound: WAN | Outbound: LAN)_.

Comment: My WAN is being done via the laptop's WiFi, I believe I'll only need 1 physical port between my laptop and dell server.

Comment: WiFi and ethernet are two physical adapters _(I should have used adapters, not ports)_

Comment: I understand that, in my case the VMs on Dell Server connect Firewall/Router via the Ethernet, which then traverses traffic to internet via the WiFi NIC.